# Django runserver UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, django

I am trying use create Django Server in Windows
and when type command "python manage.py runserver"
it pop out these error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I don't what going on and how to slove this

here is my pip freeze out

```
appdirs==1.4.3
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.5.0.1
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
certifi==2015.11.20.1
cx-Freeze==5.0.1
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.0.6
Django==1.11.4
functools32==3.2.3.post2
future==0.16.0
ipykernel==4.2.2
ipython==4.0.3
ipython-genutils==0.1.0
Jinja2==2.8
jsonschema==2.5.1
jupyter-client==4.1.1
jupyter-core==4.0.6
lxml==3.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==2.0.2
mistune==0.7.1
MySQL-python==1.2.4b4
nbconvert==4.1.0
nbformat==4.0.1
notebook==4.1.0
numpy==1.12.1
packaging==16.8
path.py==8.1.2
pickleshare==0.6
py2exe==0.6.9
py2exe-py2==0.6.9
Pygments==2.1
PyInstaller==3.2.1
pyparsing==2.2.0
pypiwin32==219
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2017.2
pyzmq==15.2.0
requests==2.9.1
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.10.0
tornado==4.3
traitlets==4.1.0
virtualenv==15.1.0
xmltodict==0.10.2
```

maybe I have some verson problem?

Comment: What version of python are you using and also edit your post with your pip freeze output, maybe the problem is a library, but you need to check if you have any special char in your code like á, ë, ñ etc

Comment: I did't use any special char in my code for sure, and I update pip freeze output above.

Comment: I find it very specious that the character in question is the "end paragraph mark" `¶`. I'm mostly a Linux guy, but there is something about windows and that character I have seen before...

Comment: Perhaps paste the entire error log when u run `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 1):

The most probable thing is that you have a char in your username that is not ascii. 
This is a known issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue9377
Dont know why it is taking so long to fix :D